# class instance from nowhere

Tags: python-3.x, boost-python, python-asyncio

I have small `aiohttp` server that takes a string from user, passes it through two Python classes to function written in `C++` with `Boost.Python` library.

Travel of the string (from user input):

`browser -> wsgi -> aiohttp -> Handler class -> Manager class -> C++ library`

After successfully writing and testing `aiohhtp` server and `Manager` Python class I have started writing `Handler` Python class. Code:

```
# ----------- handler.py ----------------
import manager
class Handler:
    manager = manager.manager()
    func = manager.func
    async def handle(self, string):
        return await self.manager.execute(self.func, string)
# ------------ manager.py ----------------
import boost_module
def func(string):
    return boost_module.cpp_func(string)
class Manager:
    async def execute(self, func, string):
        return func(string)
```

When I run `aiohttp` server as always, `TypeError: func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` raises in `Manager.execute` method. I have tried to debug it with Pycharm and by just `print(string)`, but on every step (inside every called function) `string` variable contain just a string.

Then I have tried to change `manager.func` signature:

```
# ------------ manager.py ---------------
def func(*args):
    print(args)
```

And it outputs `(<handler.Handler object at x...>, 'string')`.

How could it be?

How to fix it (not just `string = args[1]`) ?

*P.S.* sorry for bad title. I just don't know how to shortly describe what is going on.

*P.P.S.* Code above isn't the original code. I have rewritten it to focus on the problem, and it can contain some errors because it's not tested.

**UPDATE**

I can reproduce this error with this simple Python script:

```
def func(string):
    print(string)
class Manager:
    async def execute(self, func, string):
        print(self, func, string)  # point "A"
        return func(string)  # point "B"
class Handler:
    manager = Manager()
    func = func
    async def handle(self, string):
        return await self.manager.execute(self.func, string)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        Handler().handle('string'))
```

If I'm running this script, it prints to console this string (point "A"):

```
<__main__.Manager object at 0x7f5880966208> <bound method func of <__main__.Handler object at 0x7f58809664a8>> string
```

.. and then raises an error (point "B"):

```
TypeError: func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

It isn't duplicate with this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Comment: Aren't you missing some `self` arguments in your methods?

Comment: I believe the solution would be to do `func = staticmethod(manager.func)` but that isn't obvious by the marked duplicate... @JimFasarakisHillard are you sure that's the best dup target?

Comment: @JimFasarakisHillard I have updated the question and I doesn't understand how your proposed question can be the same.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen `manager.func` isn't the method - it's a function from another module (if you a talking about first code sample). Why is this working?

Comment: any python function placed in a class definition is a method - doesn't matter where it comes from.  So since you have `func = manager.func` in the class defintion and later `self.func` you are using it as a method, you can remove the method behaviour by making it a `staticmethod`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It really helps! Thank you! That the real answer on my question.