# Python error "__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python, just writing a noddy example, getting a weird error.

display.py

```
import abc
from graphics import *

class Display:
    pass

class Visual(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """Represents a thing which can be drawn on a display"""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def draw(disp: Display) -> None:
        """Draws the visual to the display"""
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Display(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        __visuals = []

    def add_visual( vis: Visual ):
        __visuals.append(vis)

    def draw() -> None:
        for visual in __visuals:
            visual.draw(self)
```

graphics_display.py

```
from graphics import *
from gfx.display import Display

class GraphicsDisplay(Display):
    def __init__(self, window : GraphWin) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        __window = window

    def get_window() -> GraphWin:
        return __window
```

The traceback is

```
>>> win = GraphWin()
>>> display = GraphicsDisplay(window=win)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/julian/test/gfx_test/gfx/graphics_display.py", line 6, in __init__
    Display.__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

graphics.py is here

Why does it think the base **init** is getting 2 arguments?

Comment: a similar issue and very good explanation is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657

Comment: D'oh! Spot the C++ programmer trying to python. That bloody self is going to get me every time.

Comment: try  adding self as first argument to the method.

Answer (score -1):

You've defined the argument window as a positional argument but then initialized it using a keyword argument.

This is the correct way based on how you defined GraphicsDisplay init:

```
display = GraphicsDisplay(win)
```

Alternatively, change your init definition to be a keyword argument with a default value:

```
class GraphicsDisplay(Display):
    def __init__(self, window : GraphWin=None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        __window = window
```

Comment: Unless the parameter is defined as a positional-only parameter (`def __init__(self, window, /): ...`, you can use either a positional or a keyword argument to assign the parameter a value.

Answer (score -2):

That line should look like this:

```
super(GraphicsDisplay, self).__init__()
```

When you're calling `super()` without arguments, you're getting non-bound parent class instance, so method `__init__()` don't get `self` objects passed as first argument.

The problem also might be with class overriding

Comment: That changed in python 3.  super().__init__() is the right way to do it.

Comment: `super` with no arguments was never legal in Python 2. You had to supply at least a class argument.