# Unexpected TypeError in a function call with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, typeerror

I am using Kivy with Python 3.5. I'm trying to set up an App where a button press schedules a function call. A premise: this is my first application with Kivy, and I am not very good with Python. Here's my simplified code:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        TextStream = Label(text = 'Something will be written here: ')
        StartButton = Button(text = 'Start writing')
        StartButton.bind(on_press=lambda x:self.start_program(freq=10))
        layout.add_widget(TextStream)
        layout.add_widget(StartButton)
        return layout

    def start_program(self, freq):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.write_something, 1.0/freq)
        # Also tried Clock.schedule_interval(self.write_something(), 1.0/freq)

    def write_something(self):
        TextStream.text =+ 'Something '

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

What I get when I run the script is:

```
TypeError: write_something() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given), about this specific error, I understood that methods in Python are actually implemented differently from how they appear in code.

More precisely, from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given#comment75940837_23944658) I understand that properly declaring the method `write_something` giving it `self` as argument is the correct way to do it. Also, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42016399/1844776) I get that the number of passed arguments counted by Python should be 1+N, where N are passed in the call. I am not passing any argument in the call however.

So, are there some silent arguments passed with Kivy? Am I calling the method in the wrong way?

**Edit - Error stack**

As suggested by a comment, I include the entire error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-5d17b5569154>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/raggot/Projects/MyApp/scripts/_test_kivy.py', wdir='/home/raggot/Projects/MyApp/scripts')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/raggot/Projects/MyApp/scripts/_test_kivy_camera.py", line 78, in <module>
    MyApp().run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 826, in run
    runTouchApp()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
    EventLoop.window.mainloop()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 403, in mainloop
    self._mainloop()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 289, in _mainloop
    EventLoop.idle()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 337, in idle
    Clock.tick()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 581, in tick
    self._process_events()

  File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events

  File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events

  File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events

  File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick

TypeError: write_something() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `()` from `self.write_something()` in `start_program()`? Please include the full traceback

Comment: change to `Clock.schedule_interval(self.write_something, 1.0/freq)`. schedule_interval you want to pass the function, and you are passing the evaluated function.

Comment: what is `InfoStream`?

Comment: @roganjosh, I actually tried both. The resulting error was the same

Comment: @raggot change to `Clock.schedule_interval(self.write_something, 1.0/freq)` and `def write_something(self, *args):`

Comment: @eyllanesc: Thank you, that worked! Or well, it triggered another error because `write_something` does not have access to the object `TextStream`, but at least the call goes through. If you can elaborate what happens in an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it connects any event, in this case `schedule_interval` Kivy passes additional arguments to it, for that reason it throws you that error, in your case it only uses `args` and you don't have any problem. In the case of `Clock`, it passes the `dt` which is the exact call time.

```
def start_program(self, freq):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.write_something, 1.0/freq)

def write_something(self, *args):
    print(args)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why examples scripts of Kivy included `**kwargs` as an extra input. Do you know why the `**kwargs` rather than `*args`?

Comment: @raggot Do you understand that they are the `*args`, and `**kwargs`? Do you know the difference?

Comment: Google just instructed me about it. Appreciate your help!