# @classmethod error: TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-model-utils

I have a model/class like this:

```
class MyModel(TimeStampedModel):
    some_field = models.CharField()

    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls, value, other_value):
        print(value)
```

However, when I do this from another view:

```
value = "Test"
MyModel.my_class_method(value, other_value)
```

I get an error: `TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

I feel like I am going crazy.

The model that I am doing this to has:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Edit: Full traceback (using my real function names):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\base.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\middleware.py", line 25, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\config\wsgi.py", line 27, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\vendor_app\apps\users\decorators.py", line 14, in wrap
    return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\PycharmProjects\webapp\vendor_app\apps\core\locations\views.py", line 56, in location_detail_view
    Location.create_or_update_location(form, formset)
TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Also added an issue in the django-model-utils issue tracker: https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/issues/342

Comment: I think it is something to do with `__call__` on abstract models. I am trying to debug (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944658/1689262)

Comment: It might be useful to see the rest of the traceback

Comment: Added the traceback (with my real function and model names)

Comment: After seeing that, it may be the @classmethod wrapper which is causing me trouble.

Comment: Yeah - it looks like you have a custom decorator in `apps\users\decorators.py` - my guess is that somewhere there you're mangling the args.

Comment: This is still causing me an issue. And still driving me crazy.

Comment: I was able to pass my kwargs like so and it works, `my_class_method(**kwargs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been caused by wrapping a classmethod also in a transaction atomic decorator:

```
@transaction.atomic
@classmethod
def my_function(cls, **kwargs):
    ... my function
```

Apparently this doesn't seem to work.