# Creating a sparse matrix: TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python

I am trying to create a sparse matrix for my decision tree algorithm in python. See my code below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

# loading the txt files
trainData=np.loadtxt('trainData.txt')
testData=np.loadtxt('testData.txt')
trainLabel=np.loadtxt('trainLabel.txt')
testLabel=np.loadtxt('testLabel.txt')

#convert trainData and testData into sparse matrices

nWords = max(max(trainData[:,1]),max(testData[:,1]))
trainDataSparse = sparse.csr_matrix(trainData[:,0],trainData[:,1],np.ones(len(trainData)),max(trainData[:,0]),nWords)
testDataSparse = sparse.csc_matrix(testData[:,0],testData[:,1],np.ones(len(testData)),max(testData[:,0]),nWords)
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
trainDataSparse = sparse.csr_matrix(trainData[:,0],trainData[:,1],np.ones(len(trainData)),max(trainData[:,0]),nWords)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

From what I see, I am only entering five arguments to the function, where is that sixth argument that error is talking about? and how to fix that?

Comment: In regards of your error on the number of argument, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given) there is a somewhat deeper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The [correct signature for `csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) is:

```
csr_matrix(arg1, shape=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

It's hard for me to tell from your code what you want to do, so I can't suggest a fix, but the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) has many examples that you can look at.

The reason why you see 6 instead of 5 is because the implicit `self` argument is added to the count.

Comment: Is there a way to work around that, especially that I am not the one creating the class