# Nested view in django giving TypeError because of additional argument passed to __init__()

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments

I have a view in which I am attempting to do all of the following:

- Extend an existing form to have additional fields that do not
  correspond to a model
- Check if form data is valid
- Generate a stripe token and process a charge
- If that charge is successful, save non cc fields in the form to my local db

I believe my logic is all correct here, and that if a charge is created, then form fields that correspond to my model will be saved to my db, and the user will be shown a success page, or an error page otherwise.

However, when attempting to test, I get the error:

```
TypeError at /url/linked/to/view
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

In attempting to solve this problem on my own, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given) question. Based on answers to that question, the short answer seems to be that adding `self` as first argument to the relevant method should resolve the issue, although it doesn't appear to in this case.

My view:

```
class payment_order(View):
    def post(self, request):
        card_num = request.POST['card_num']
        exp_month = request.POST['exp_month']
        exp_year = request.POST['exp_year']
        cvc = request.POST['cvc']
        email = request.POST['email']
        cart = Cart(request)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = OrderPayForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():

                token = stripe.Token.create(
                  card={
                  "number": card_num,
                  "exp_month": int(exp_month),
                  "exp_year": int(exp_year),
                  "cvc": cvc
                   },
                )

                charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                  amount=cart.item['price'],
                  currency="usd",
                  source=token,
                  description="order for "+ email
                )

                if charge['captured'] == True:
                    order = form.save()
                    for item in cart:
                        OrderItem.objects.create(
                            order=order,
                            product=item['product'],
                            price=item['price'],
                        )
                    return render(request, 'orders/created.html', {'order': order})
                else:
                    form = OrderPayForm()
                    return render(request, 'orders/create.html', {'form': form})
```

I have not overridden `__init__()`, and aside from using stripe methods and having a deeper level of nesting than my other views, I don't think I am doing anything unusual. What is causing this error in this instance?

Comment: Isn't there an indentation error in `return` statements?

Comment: @Paandittya I don't believe so, although I just edited my question to ensure I pasted my view as it currently is. I was getting a syntax error previously that was due to indentation issues, but I believe how I have it now to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I will remove this answer if someone posts a better solution, but I thought it might help others in case they encounter a similar issue.

Basically, I have solved this by switching from a class based view to a function based view, and changing the logic on the last few lines slightly.

My new view that seems to be working:

```
def payment_order(request):
    card_num = request.POST.get('card_num', False)
    exp_month = request.POST.get('exp_month', False)
    exp_year = request.POST.get('exp_year ', False)
    cvc = request.POST.get('cvc', False)
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderPayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            token = stripe.Token.create(
              card={
              "number": card_num,
              "exp_month": int(exp_month),
              "exp_year": int(exp_year),
              "cvc": cvc
               },
            )

            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
              amount=cart.item['price'],
              currency="usd",
              source=token,
              description="order for "+ email
            )

            if charge['captured'] == True:
                order = form.save()
                for item in cart:
                    OrderItem.objects.create(
                        order=order,
                        product=item['product'],
                        price=item['price'],
                    )
                return render(request, 'orders/created.html', {'order': order})
    form = OrderPayForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/create.html', {'form': form})
```