# Does self is required in python function if it going to be used directly instead of class object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following class and a function defined in it.

```
class utils:
    def pass_hash(unhashed):
        hashed = hashlib.sha256(unhashed)
        hashed = hashed.hexdigest()
        return hashed
```

When I call

```
print(utils.pass_hash('abc'.encode()))
```

it works fine but if i call

```
obj = utils()
print(obj.pass_hash('abc'.encode()))
```

it gives following error:

```
  print(obj.pass_hash('abc'.encode()))
TypeError: pass_hash() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Whereas if I pass self argument in function then this bheaviour gets reversed i.e. it works fine with object but on accesing like utils.pass_hash() it gives error.

Can someone please exlain this behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Comment: This should not be a method on a class at all. Python is not Java, it does not require everything to be defined in a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the usual behaviour of classes and their instances.

If you do `obj = utils()`, you create an instance of the class `utils` (which should better be named `Utils`). If you perform an instance method call such as `obj.pass_hash(x)`, `obj` is automatically passed as a first argument to the method and `x` as second one. Thus, it is required that the method is defined as `def pass_hash(self, x)`.

If you want to call a method on the class itself, you have to annotate it with `@staticmethod` or with `@classmethod`.

A `@staticmethod` changes the described behaviour in so far as the auto-passing of `self` is suppressed. A `@classmethod` has the method called with the class object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `obj.pass_hash('abc'.encode())` is the same as calling

```
utils.pass_hash(obj,'abc'.encode())
```

The first parameter is the instance the method was called on. (It probably does not need to be called `self`, but not doing so would be confusing for other readers).

Answer (score 0):

So class methods need to know what class they belong to. If a method doesn't need self then it is most likely a function and should be outside of that class or in a different class.

The error comes up due to you calling it on a specific object rather than the class itself, so when you call it via `utils` it calls the general class method while calling it via

```py
obj = utils()
print(obj.pass_hash('abc'.encode()))
```

calls that method within the `obj` object.

In this example, I would recommend refactoring to make the `pass_hash` method into a function, if you find that you make a lot more use of similar hash-editing functions then feel free to make a `HashHandler` class.