# Query over inheriting from Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner of python and I came across such a problem. When I tried to create my own class, which is a subclass, I came across such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    class gender(Enum):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python365_64bit\lib\enum.py", line 208, in __new__
    enum_member.__init__(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The class I made is:

```py
class gender(Enum):
    Male = 0
    Female = 1

    def __init__(self):
        if self.value == 0:
            self.sex = 'Boy'
        else:
            self.sex = 'Girl'

    def getsex(self):
        print('This person is ',self.sex)
```

Just want to know why __init__ is not working ....

Comment: 1) remove `__init__ ...`    2) use `def get_sex(self):
        print('This person is ', 'Boy' if self.value == Gender.Male else "Girl")`

Comment: How did you initialize the class `gender` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed wrong number of arguments to `__init__`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given) for information about `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` error.

I've modified your code like this. See if this fits you.

```
from enum import Enum

class Gender(Enum):
    Male = 0
    Female = 1
    sex = ''

    def __init__(self, value):
        if value == 0:
            self.sex = 'Boy'
        else:
            self.sex = 'Girl'

    def getsex(self):
        print('This person is ',self.sex)


# The following is how I use the class:

g = Gender(Gender.Female)
g.getsex()
```

The `value` in `def __init__(self, value):` represents the parameter,`Gender.Female` I passed in.

The `self` in `def __init__(self, value):` represents the instance of `Gender`.

When I call `Gender(Gender.Female)`, python calls `__init__(self, Gender.Female)` behind the scenes. That's the reason for adding the new argument `value` to `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks Brian, just a quick question. What is the reason to add value into the __init__? can you shed more light?