# How does python pass the first variable in Class/Instance

Tags: python, python-internals

In my class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = None
```

How does python "know" to pass `MyClass` as the first argument to init when doing:

```
MyClass()
```

Likewise, if I had a classmethod, how would python "know" to pass `MyClass` as the first argument (cls) in that as well?

Comment: It does **not** pass `MyClass` as the first argument. The `__new__` method instantiates the actual instance then `__init__` initialises it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new).

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944658/10746224) has an excellent explanation for what happens behind the scenes with `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply how the interpreter (or compiler) is written. It is the job of the interpreter (or compiler) to recognize that

```
MyClass()
```

is supposed to initialize a `MyClass` object and call the `__init__` method with the newly created object as the `self` parameter. Note that, as one of the comments noted, it is the new object which is assigned to the `self` parameter, and not `MyClass`.

In the case where you're calling a non-initializer method, the interpreter (or compiler) likewise knows that you're calling a method, so it puts the object as the first argument.