# Function name is not defined in a Python class

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a class like below:

```
class Logger:

    @staticmethod
    def get_timestamp():
        import datetime
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    
    def print_log(self,color, write_level, msg):
        return color

    def log_level_print(self,log_level, write_level, msg):
        if log_level == 'ERROR':
            return print_log(bcolors.FAIL, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'WARN':
            return print_log(bcolors.WARNING, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'INFO':
            return print_log(bcolors.OKGREEN, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'DEBUG':
            return print_log(bcolors.OKBLUE, write_level, msg)
        else:
            print(f"{Logger.get_timestamp()} {bcolors.FAIL}: Invalid LOG type{bcolors.ENDC}")
            return
```

Here, I am using this class :

```
from logger import Logger
demo = Logger()
print(demo.log_level_print('ERROR','ssdsd','sdsdsd'))
```

I am not able to call this function, I'm getting an error:
`NameError: name 'print_log' is not defined`

Comment: Shouldn't you give the function 3rd argument?

Comment: You forgot the `self` as first argument in the definition of `log_level_print`... (same goes for `print_log` by the way)

Comment: The first argument should be `self`, change it to `log_level_print(self, log_level, write_level, msg`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add `self` as the first argument of class' methods and when you use the methods. Corrected code:

```py
class Logger:
    @staticmethod
    def get_timestamp():
        import datetime
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def print_log(self, color, write_level, msg):
        return color

    def log_level_print(self, log_level, write_level, msg):
        if log_level == 'ERROR':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.FAIL, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'WARN':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.WARNING, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'INFO':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.OKGREEN, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'DEBUG':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.OKBLUE, write_level, msg)
        else:
            print(f"{Logger.get_timestamp()} {bcolors.FAIL}: Invalid LOG type{bcolors.ENDC}")
            return
```

---

Look, it's a code I'm running:

```
demo = Logger()
print(demo.log_level_print('ERROR','ssdsd','sdsdsd'))
```

and this is a result:
[image: 2]

Comment: static methods does not need self

Comment: Right, my bad. Edited.

Comment: I'm running this code (without `bcolors`) and there is no error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a `self`.
All (EDIT: non static, nor abstract) class methods should have a parameter which is typically named `self`, like so:

```py
class Logger():
    @staticmethod
    def get_timestamp():
        ...

    def print_log(self, color, write_level, msg):
        ...

    def log_level_print(self, log_level, write_level, msg):
        ...


demo = Logger()
print(demo.log_level_print('ERROR','ssdsd','sdsdsd'))
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I've edited it a couple of minutes ago (indents).

Comment: I updated the answer to conform with your feedback, let me know if there's still something wrong.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, because no one had approved my edit by the time.

Comment: @maciejwww oh I didn't notice you were not the OP... ^_^

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you need to call `self` and scondly it will still throw error if `bcolors` is not specified. You need to call `bcolors`. I am assuming that it is some another dependency which you have not specified.

Here is a sample.

```py
class Logger:
    @staticmethod
    def get_timestamp(self):
        import datetime
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def print_log(self, color, write_level, msg):
        return color

    def log_level_print(self, log_level, write_level, msg):

        bcolors = []  # temporary empty list

        if log_level == 'ERROR':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.FAIL, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'WARN':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.WARNING, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'INFO':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.OKGREEN, write_level, msg)
        if log_level == 'DEBUG':
            return self.print_log(bcolors.OKBLUE, write_level, msg)
        else:
            print(f"{Logger.get_timestamp()} {bcolors.FAIL}: Invalid LOG type{bcolors.ENDC}")
            return

demo = Logger()
print(demo.log_level_print('ERROR','ssdsd','sdsdsd'))
```

Comment: static methods does not need self as a parameter. I am still getting print_log is not defined error!, I added self to other function

Comment: Did you really add `self.` before `print_log`? This code works for me like in my answer.

Comment: Yes I have added self to the print_log but not to static function.But I am still getting the same error