# Get an error with my python function saying TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, function

I have an issue with the calendar function. My code is below and i get the following error

```
StartDT = df_pandas.iloc[1]['Effectivedate'].date()
month = StartDT.month - 1 + 1
year = StartDT.year + month // 12
month = month % 12 + 1
day = min(StartDT.day, calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1])
```

----> 6 day = min(StartDT.day, calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1])

TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Could someone please help me

Comment: show the full traceback you get. Also post [MCVE]

Comment: I think you may have accidentally redefined `monthrange.calendar()`. Note that the traceback refers to the function `_()`. That can only happen if your code does something like `calendar.traceback = _`.

Answer (score 0):

Does you function `calendar.monthrange` have **self** as first argument ?

```py
class calendar:
    def monthrange(self, year, month):
        pass
```

Also Does this solve your problem ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Comment: `calendar.monthrange` isn't OP's function: `calendar` is a module in the standard library.