# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given // Linked Lists

Tags: python, linked-list, typeerror

The class **Node** instantiates with a value and a reference to the next node in the linked list. The value of the node is accessible by **value** on the node. A reference to the next node in the list is accessible via an **next** on the node.

The function **insert** that takes a reference to the 1st node in a linked list, a new **value**, and a position and inserts a new node with the given value at the given position in the list.

The function **pop** to takes a reference to the 1st node in a linked list and a position and removes the node at that position in the linked list.

The function **stringify_linked_list** that takes a reference to the first node of a linked list and returnes a printable string of all nodes in the linked list.

However, when I try to test it out by

```
assert repr(Node(-1, None)) == '<Node (-1)>'
```

and

```
n1 = Node(4, None)
assert n1.value == 4
assert n1.next is None
```

I get a TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

My code so far is below. If you have any ideas on how I can fix it, please let me know. Thank you!

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None 

def insert(head, value, position):
    new = Node(value) 
    if position ==1: 
        new.next = head
        return new
    current_index = 1
    current_node = head
   
    while current_index< position-1 and current_node is not None:
        current_node = current_node.next
        current_index +=1

    if current_node is None: 
        raise IndexError("Insertion position invalid!")
    else: 
        new.next = current_node.next 
        current_node.next = new 
        return head

def pop(head, position):
    if position==1: 
        return head, head.next 
    current_index = 1
    current_node = head
    while current_index<position-1 and current_node is not None:
        current_node = current_node.next
        current_index += 1
    if current_node is None:
        raise IndexError("Pop position invalid!")
    else:
        current_node.next = current_node.next.next
        return current_node.next , head


def stringify_linked_list(head):
    ret_string = "" 
    pointer = head
    counter = 1
    while pointer is not None:
        ret_string += (str(counter)+":"+str(pointer.value)+"  ") 
        pointer = pointer.next
        counter+=1
    return ret_string
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 2):

Your `__init__` takes two parameters: `self` and `value`.

When you create a new object in python, self is always automatically passed to the constructor as reference to the newly created object (itself).
So your `__init__` expects two parameters, but you already pass two - and self gets added as the third one. When you call `Node(4, None)`, `__init__` gets called as `__init__(self, 4, None)`, but it only expects `__init__(self, 4)`.

To fix this, either add a third parameter in your init or remove the second parameter in your calls to Node() (which is None anyways?).