# Why do I get an error when calling my method?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have created a paint UI and I want to change the size of the brush using a QSlider.

I want to call a method when the user changes the value of the slider

```
brushThick = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
value = brushThick.value()
brushThick.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
brushThick.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 30)
lcd = QLCDNumber(self)

brushSize.valueChanged.connect(lcd.display)
```

I call this method when the slider has moved

```
brushThick.sliderMoved.connect(self.changeBrushSize(value))
```

The method I am calling is

```
def changeBrushSize(self, size):
    self.brushSize = size
```

I am new to python and do not understand why it is not accepting the size when it is passed. I store the size using the `value()` which returns a `int`. I can set `brushSize` manually and it works but not dynamically when the user uses the slider.

The error I am getting is

```
brushThick.sliderMoved.connect(self.changeBrushSize(value))
TypeError: changeBrushSize() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I have read this post but still do not understand

[TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Full Code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QFileDialog, QSlider, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QLCDNumber, \
    QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QSplitter, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QImage, QPainter, QPen, QPixmap
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint

class PaintingApplication(QMainWindow): # documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html
    '''
    Painting Application class
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # set window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Paint Application")

        # set the windows dimensions
        top = 400
        left = 400
        width = 800
        height = 600
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)

        #set the icon
        # windows version
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./icons/paint-brush.png")) # documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop
        # mac version - not yet working
        # self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("./icons/paint-brush.png")))

        # image settings (default)
        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32) # documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-1
        self.image.fill(Qt.white) # documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fill-1

        # draw settings (default)
        self.drawing = False
        self.brushSize = 3
        self.brushColor = Qt.black # documenation: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/Qt.html

        # reference to last point recorded by mouse
        self.lastPoint = QPoint() # documenation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpoint.html

        # set up menus
        mainMenu = self.menuBar() # create and a menu bar
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu(" File") # add the file menu to the menu bar, the space is required as "File" is reserved in Mac
        brushSizeMenu = mainMenu.addMenu(" Brush Size") # add the "Brush Size" menu to the menu bar
        brushColorMenu = mainMenu.addMenu(" Brush Colour") # add the "Brush Colour" menu to the menu bar

        # save menu item
        saveAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/save.png"), "Save", self)   # create a save action with a png as an icon, documenation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")                                # connect this save action to a keyboard shortcut, documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#shortcut-prop
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)                                  # add the save action to the file menu, documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addAction
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)                         # when the menu option is selected or the shortcut is used the save slot is triggered, documenation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered

        # clear
        clearAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/clear.png"), "Clear", self) # create a clear action with a png as an icon
        clearAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")                                # connect this clear action to a keyboard shortcut
        fileMenu.addAction(clearAction)                                  # add this action to the file menu
        clearAction.triggered.connect(self.clear)                        # when the menu option is selected or the shortcut is used the clear slot is triggered


        # brush thickness
        threepxAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/threepx.png"), "3px", self)
        threepxAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+3") #TODO changed the control options to be numbers
        brushSizeMenu.addAction(threepxAction) # connect the action to the function below
        threepxAction.triggered.connect(self.threepx)

        fivepxAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/fivepx.png"), "5px", self)
        fivepxAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+5")
        brushSizeMenu.addAction(fivepxAction)
        fivepxAction.triggered.connect(self.fivepx)

        sevenpxAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/sevenpx.png"), "7px", self)
        sevenpxAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+7")
        brushSizeMenu.addAction(sevenpxAction)
        sevenpxAction.triggered.connect(self.sevenpx)

        ninepxAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/ninepx.png"), "9px", self)
        ninepxAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+9")
        brushSizeMenu.addAction(ninepxAction)
        ninepxAction.triggered.connect(self.ninepx)

        # brush colors
        blackAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/black.png"), "Black", self)
        blackAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+B")
        brushColorMenu.addAction(blackAction);
        blackAction.triggered.connect(self.black)

        redAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/red.png"), "Red", self)
        redAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+R")
        brushColorMenu.addAction(redAction);
        redAction.triggered.connect(self.red)

        greenAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/green.png"), "Green", self)
        greenAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+G")
        brushColorMenu.addAction(greenAction);
        greenAction.triggered.connect(self.green)

        yellowAction = QAction(QIcon("./icons/yellow.png"), "Yellow", self)
        yellowAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Y")
        brushColorMenu.addAction(yellowAction);
        yellowAction.triggered.connect(self.yellow)



        # A QSlider to change the size of the brush
        #   - Qt.Horizontal insure the slider scales horizontally
        #   - Creating a label for the slider
        brushThick = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        value = brushThick.value()
        brushThick.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        brushThick.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 30)
        lcd = QLCDNumber(self)

        brushThick.valueChanged.connect(lcd.display)
        brushThick.sliderMoved.connect(self.changeBrushSize(1))



        lcd.move(550, 50)
        brushThick.move(550, 100)
        self.show()



    # Change Brush Size
    def changeBrushSize(self, value):
        self.brushSize = value



    # event handlers
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):       # when the mouse is pressed, documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent
        if event.button() ==Qt.LeftButton:  # if the pressed button is the left button
            self.drawing = True             # enter drawing mode
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()    # save the location of the mouse press as the lastPoint
            print(self.lastPoint)           # print the lastPoint for debigging purposes

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):                        # when the mouse is moved, documenation: documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent
     if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton & self.drawing:     # if there was a press, and it was the left button and we are in drawing mode
            painter = QPainter(self.image)                  # object which allows drawing to take place on an image
            # allows the selection of brush colour, brish size, line type, cap type, join type. Images available here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())   # draw a line from the point of the orginal press to the point to where the mouse was dragged to
            self.lastPoint= event.pos()                     # set the last point to refer to the point we have just moved to, this helps when drawing the next line segment
            self.update()                                   # call the update method of the widget which calls the paintEvent of this class

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):                     # when the mouse is released, documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:                   # if the released button is the left button, documenation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MouseButton-enum ,
            self.drawing = False                            # exit drawing mode

    # paint events
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # you should only create and use the QPainter object in this method, it should be a local variable
        canvasPainter = QPainter(self)                      # create a new QPainter object, documenation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect()) # draw the image , documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage-1

    # resize event - this fuction is called
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.image = self.image.scaled(self.width(), self.height())

    # slots
    def save(self):
        filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Image","", "PNG(*.png);;JPG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files (*.*)")
        if filePath =="": # if the file path is empty
            return # do nothing and return
        self.image.save(filePath) # save file image to the file path


    def clear(self):
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)   # fill the image with white, documentaiton: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fill-2
        self.update()               # call the update method of the widget which calls the paintEvent of this class

    def threepx(self):              # the brush size is set to 3
        self.brushSize = 3

    def fivepx(self):
        self.brushSize = 5

    def sevenpx(self):
        self.brushSize = 7

    def ninepx(self):
        self.brushSize = 9

    def black(self):                # the brush color is set to black
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

    def black(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

    def red(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.red

    def green(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.green

    def yellow(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.yellow

    # open a file
    def open(self):
        '''
        This is an additional function which is not part of the tutorial. It will allow you to:
         - open a file doalog box,
         - filter the list of files according to file extension
         - set the QImage of your application (self.image) to a scaled version of the file)
         - update the widget
        '''
        filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Image", "",
                                                  "PNG(*.png);;JPG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files (*.*)")
        if filePath == "":   # if not file is selected exit
            return
        with open(filePath, 'rb') as f: #open the file in binary mode for reading
            content = f.read() # read the file
        self.image.loadFromData(content) # load the data into the file
        width = self.width() # get the width of the current QImage in your application
        height = self.height() # get the height of the current QImage in your application
        self.image = self.image.scaled(width, height) # scale the image from file and put it in your QImage
        self.update() # call the update method of the widget which calls the paintEvent of this class



if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PaintingApplication()
    window.show()
    app.exec() # start the event loop running
```

Comment: I suspect you have multiple definitions of the method. Post your full code.

Comment: I have posted the full code, it is towards the bottom before the methods

Comment: I don't see a problem with the call to `self.changeBrushSize()`. However, you're using the result as an argument to `connect()`, and the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Didn't you post the same question earlier today? Anyway, I don't get your error _"method takes 1 argument but 2 were given"_. Instead, I get _"brushThick.sliderMoved.connect(self.changeBrushSize(1))
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'"_. You need to look up how to use `connect()`

Comment: Yes but I went to try solve it again but failed

Comment: Add `return value` to the end of `def changeBrushSize`.

Comment: And change that line to `brushThick.sliderMoved.connect(self.changeBrushSize)`. Then it works as expected https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah7iW.png

Comment: Please do not delete a question just to repost another one which is almost the same as [the deleted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114796/why-can-i-not-call-this-method-in-python-using-pyqt5), it's considered abuse, and users with enough reputation can see deleted posts also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two very important problems:

- while your `changeBrushSize` function has two (positional) arguments, the first (self) is always referred to the instance, so you should not normally provide it: when an instance method is called, the `self` is always implied, so the call should be `self.changeBrushSize(5)`, since only the second `size` argument will be used; the last error you got is because you tried to provide *more* arguments, and there's no use to that;
- `connect()` takes a **callable** as argument, while you are actually executing the function (which probably returns None), and even if you removed that `self` as explained above, the program will crash anyway because what the function returns is *not* a callable;

If you want to update the `self.brushSize` value when the slider changes, do the following:

```
    brushSize.sliderMoved.connect(self.changeBrushSize)
```

As you can see, there's no parenthesis. When the signal is emitted, Qt will **call** all slots/functions connected to it, using the signal *arguments*.

I strongly suggest you to read and study more about the following topics *starting* with the related links, as they represent the *basics* and are *fundamentals* to python and programming in general, and can never be ignored:

- [classes and instances](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)
- [what is a callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable)
- [what is the purpose of `return` and how it works with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)