# Getting an error while executing the below code in Leetcode under Python3 while reversing a string using recursion method

Tags: python, string, recursion, syntax, reverse

I am doing leetcode problems on basics of python. I am getting error code as below on leetcode.

```
TypeError: reverseString() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given ret = Solution().reverseString(param_1) Line 28 in _driver (Solution.py) _driver()
```

```
 class Solution:
        def reverseString(s: List[str]) -> None:
            if len(s)==0:
                return s
            else:
                return Solution.reverseString(s[1:])+s[0]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 0):

`reverseString` is a class method but you didn't define a `self` parameter as the first argument. You should either put that in as the first argument, or use the [`@staticmethod` decorator](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/). This is explained much better in this existing post: [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide one argument instead of two.

Comment: I don't think this answer really explains why two arguments are being passed when their code (`Solution().reverseString(param_1)`) only sends one. The reason Python thinks two arguments are being sent is because it's a class method, so Python is automatically sending `self` as the first argument.