# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given "TypeError at /hello/"

Tags: python, django, django-views, anaconda, backend

I tried to setup hello world project but it gives me this error:

```
TypeError at /hello/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: C:\Users\usama\OneDrive\Documents\atom\Django\FirstPro\app\views.py, line 7, in index
Python Executable:  C:\Users\usama\anaconda3\envs\MyEnv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\usama\\OneDrive\\Documents\\atom\\Django\\FirstPro',
 'C:\\Users\\usama\\anaconda3\\envs\\MyEnv\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\usama\\anaconda3\\envs\\MyEnv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\usama\\anaconda3\\envs\\MyEnv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\usama\\anaconda3\\envs\\MyEnv',
 'C:\\Users\\usama\\anaconda3\\envs\\MyEnv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return HttpRequest('hello , world!')
```

**installed app in project's setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you are using `HttpRequest` but the Django view must return a **response**.
Use this:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    # pay attention this is HttpResponse not HttpRequest
    return HttpResponse('hello , world!')
```