# Python Django __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, web

Hi i started to make django and started with simple Hi app. But when i want to access on /hi/ i give error called "**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Here is code

```
#urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from hi.views import hiView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hi/', hiView),
]
```

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest


def hiView(request):
    return HttpRequest('Hi.')
```

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hi',
]
```

im adding my directory list https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZWug.jpg

Comment: Can you add the error stack trace ?

Comment: where i can find error stack trace?

Comment: You write `return HttpRequest('Hi.')`. `HttpRequest` is the class used for the request **from** the user. You likely want to use `HttpResponse` instead.

Comment: Just before the error message in the console (before `__init__() takes ...`).
Or in the django error page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_init\_\_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given "TypeError at /hello/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65911851/init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-typeerror-at-hello)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send a `HttpRequest` instead of `HttpResponse`.

The `HttpRequest.__init__` method only takes one argument : `self`, which is automatically passed by python when you create a new instance.