# thread does not start:TypeError: backgroundTask() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am learning multithreading in python. can anyone pleae tell me why the thread does not start?

**code**:
import threading
import time
import logging

```
class Threads_2:

def __new__(cls):
    """
    this will be invoked once the creation procedure of the object begins
    """
    instance = super(Threads_2,cls).__new__(cls)
    return instance

def __init__(self):
    """
    this will be invoked once the initialisation procedure of the object begins
    """
    #self.configLogging()
    #threadinf.Thread.__init__(self)
    #self.spawnThreads()

def spawnThreads(self):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.backgroundTask, args=(10,))
        thread1.start()

def backgroundTask(numOfLoops):
    for i in numOfLoops:
        print(2)


obj = Threads_2()
obj.spawnThreads()
```

**error**:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: backgroundTask() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
PS D:\python workspace>
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Comment: The site's "related questions" search works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The function backgroundTask is in the class Threads_2. So, it should be backgroundTask(self, numOfLoops) instead of backgroundTask(numOfLoops).