# Why do I get an TypeError: filterTweetList() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given error?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am currently trying to clean a csv of Twitter data as part of a pre-processing step. I currently get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...main.py", line 192, in <module>
    obj = TwitterApplication(root)
  File "...main.py", line 88, in __init__
    twitter = self.filterTweetList(df['text'])
TypeError: filterTweetList() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I saw a similar question asked ([TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)) with the main suggestion being to add "self" as the first argument yet I still end up with this error.

The error appears at `twitterData = self.filterTweetList(df['text'])`.

My current code:

```
class MainApplication:

    def __init__(self, root):

        df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

        if len(df) == 0:
            msg.showinfo('No Rows Selected')
        else:
            twitterData = self.filterTweetList(df['text'])

        print(twitterData[1]) # Call in first cleaned tweet
     

    # Functions for data cleaning

    def removePunc(myWord):
        """Function to remove punctuation from string inputs"""
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        else:
            return re.sub('[.:;()/!&-*@$,?^\d+]', '', myWord)

    def removeAscii(myWord):
        """Function to remove ascii from string input"""
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        else:
            return str(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', myWord.decode('utf-8').strip()))

    def lemmatize(myWord):
        wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
        """Function to lemmatize words"""
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        else:
            return str(wnl.lemmatize(myWord))

    def removeStopWords(myWord):
        """Function to remove stop words"""
        newStopWords = ['amp', 'rt', 'https', 'http']
        stopwords.append(newStopWords)
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        if myWord not in str(stopwords.words('english')):
            return myWord

    def removeLinkUser(myWord):
        """Function to remove web addresses and twitter handles"""
        if not myWord.startswith('@') and not myWord.startswith('http'):
            return myWord

    def prepText(myWord):
        """Final text pre-processing function"""
        return myWord.removeStopWords(
            myWord.lemmatize(
                myWord.removeAscii(
                    myWord.removePunc(
                        myWord.removeLinkUser(
                            myWord.lower()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )

    def filterTweetList(tweetList):
        """Remove stop words, lemmatize, and clean all tweets"""
        return [[tweetList.prepText(word) for word
                 in tweet.split()
                 if tweetList.prepText(word) is not None]
                for tweet in tweetList]
```

Comment: This is literally answered in the question you linked. You haven't done what the answer there told you to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, every method within a class takes `self` at the first argument. So simply replace `def removePunc(myWord)` with `def removePunc(self, myWord)` and continue that for all of the methods within the class.

Comment: That seems to have got rid of the previous error but produced ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'prepText'``` on the same line of code.

Comment: In the list comprehension at the very end, you try to call `prepText`on a list. Just remove the `tweetList` before `prepText`.