# function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-views, virtualenv

I'm trying to clone [this](https://github.com/Ehco1996/django-sspanel) Django repo and run it on my local machine, but I've run into the classic **function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given** error.

After cloning the repo I created a virtual environment and installed all the dependencies,

But when I run

```
py manage.py migrate
```

I get the above-mentioned error.

What's confusing me is that the error is occurring in a python file automatically generated in the virtual environment and according to [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given) on SO about this, the code seems correct.

Here's the trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django_prometheus\apps.py", line 22, in ready
    ExportMigrations()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django_prometheus\migrations.py", line 39, in ExportMigrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[alias])
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 202, in connect
    self.init_connection_state()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 245, in init_connection_state
    if self.features.is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\features.py", line 150, in is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled
    return self.connection.mysql_server_data['sql_auto_is_null']
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 366, in mysql_server_data
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "C:\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\work\django-sspanel\sspanel_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 237, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
TypeError: create_cursor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Base.py in the virtual environment.

```
def _cursor(self, name=None):
        self.ensure_connection()
        with self.wrap_database_errors:
            return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
```

```
def create_cursor(self, name=None):
        """Create a cursor. Assume that a connection is established."""
        raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of BaseDatabaseWrapper may require a create_cursor() method')
```

I was hoping that someone could try cloning the repo and running it locally to see whether they could recreate the problem or maybe help me understand what's causing it.

Comment: You should put the repo name in the title of your question and the tags. I bet it's going to be an incompatibility between your version of Python or Django or similar, and what the library expects.

Comment: I would but I do not have a high enough reputation to have custom tag names. Let me look into version compatibility.