# Command raised an exception: TypeError: unban() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

I was making a discord bot unban command in cog file but when I go to discord and try to unban it says

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: unban() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here's the full code

```
@commands.command(aliases=['ub'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for banned_entry in banned_users:
        user = banned_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            try:
                await member.send("You have been unbanned from Scar Community Server   https://discord.gg/bXGTk9x7 ")
            except:
                await ctx.send("Cannot DM them!")
            return
```

Comment: Missing `self`?

Comment: now it says Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'staffcmd' object has no attribute 'guild'

Comment: `self` goes as the first argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 0):

Any method of a class requires `self` as the first parameter.

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['ub'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(self, ctx, *, member):
    # ...
```