# "edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" Even though I only gave one. [Discord.PY]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I'm writing a hack command for a Discord Bot (obviously a joke) and I'm getting a weird error. It's saying I've given something that only takes 1 positional argument was given 2 arguments, even though it clearly was not.

```py
@client.command()
async def hack(message, member:discord.Member):
  message = await message.reply("**It's info yoinking time!**\nHacking "+member.name+"\n\n**This command is currently only proof-of-concept and does not work past finding password. Slend is working on a fix.**")

  await asyncio.sleep(3)

  await message.edit(content="**1/5** | Finding e-mail address...")

  await asyncio.sleep(3)

  await message.edit(content="**1/5** | E-mail address found: `"+member.name+"@discord.com`")

  await asyncio.sleep(2)

  await message.edit(content="**2/5** | Finding password to Discord Account...")

  await asyncio.sleep(3)

  await message.edit(content="**2/5** | Discord Account password found: `me("+member.name+")iscool"+member.discriminator+"`")

  await asyncio.sleep(2)

  await message.edit("**3/5** | Logging in to Discord Account...")
```

And this is my error:

```py
Ignoring exception in command hack:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 107, in hack
    await message.edit("**3/5** | Logging in to Discord Account...")
TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm not sure why it's saying that, as you can see I've indeed only given it one argument.
If this helps, it throws this error when tying to edit **from** `` **2/5** | Discord Account password found: `me("+member.name+")iscool"+member.discriminator+" `` **to** `**3/5** | Logging in to Discord Account...`

Thanks for any help! :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line is wrong, `content` is a keyword-only argument

```py
await message.edit(content="**3/5** | Logging in to Discord Account...")
```

I'm unsure why you did it wrong that last time, the attempts before were done right.

Comment: I'm not too sure what was different there, but using the fact you said "*Your last line is wrong*", I just copied one of the previous lines and changed what was said. For that reason you get that tick.

Comment: You passed the string as a positional argument, `message.edit` only takes keyword arguments.