# Class instantiation adding extra arguments to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, arguments

I have a python3 class with the following code

```
class Cow:

    def __init__(self, *bovines):
        for i in bovines:
            self.i = i
            print(i)

    def moo(a,b):
        print(a)

animal = Cow
animal.moo('a','b')
```

It prints, correctly, `a`.

However, if I run the following (the only difference being that `animal = Cow('Annie')` instead of `animal = Cow`)

```
class Cow:

    def __init__(self, *bovines):
        for i in bovines:
            self.i = i
            print(i)

    def moo(a,b):
        print(a)

animal = Cow('Annie')
animal.moo('a','b')
```

Then `moo` returns the error

```
TypeError: moo() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I imagine this has something to do with the function accepting whatever is `__init__`'d as an argument, but I'm not sure how to work around this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "I imagine this has something to do with the function accepting whatever is `__init__`'d as an argument" Notice how the code you posted does **not** contain a method named `__init__`? It has been named `__init` instead. This is, presumably, the cause of the problem - although the usage example you posted doesn't make any sense: "instantiate `animal` with `cow`" already doesn't make sense, and you show the same code block again without indicating what is done differently to cause the problem.

Comment: In the future, please don't rely on vague descriptions such as "with a structure something like this" - instead, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you.  This was an error in the formatting.  The code blocks aren't identical now.  I think this is minimal and reproducible now.  I also fixed capitalization.

Comment: I'm fixing those now.

Comment: I think this is minimal and reproducible now.

Comment: Yay it is neatly reproducible!

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given .

Comment: Your "only" difference is a *huge* difference. `animal = Cow` doesn't create an instance of `Cow` at all; it just makes `animal` another reference to the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a method for a class in python, you need to have self as the first parameter passed into the definition. See below:

```html
def moo(self, a, b):
    print(a)
```

The type error is because you are passing in self and then the parameters you'd like to pass in (a & b) to the function moo by calling it. Hence "TypeError: moo() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given".

If you were defining a function but not passing in any parameters, you'd still define it as:

```html
def foo(self):
  # do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was the issue and now this is solved.