# TypeError: get_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given for twitter bot program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import tweepy

api_key='xxx'
api_key_secret='xxx'
access_token='xxx'
access_token_secret='xxx'

authenticator=tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key,api_key_secret)
authenticator.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(authenticator, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

user = api.get_user("ammfoundation")

tweets_user=api.user_timeline(user_id=user.id)

for tweet in tweets_user:
    if not tweet.favorited:
        api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
```

Comment: You need to revoke those access credentials **now, ASAP**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)