# "TypeError: Person() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" but the constructor takes two arguments

Tags: python

This is the strangest thing. My python has just stopped handling classes with multiple parameters in their ctors? Running python 3.8.10 getting error `TypeError: Person() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
def Person(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.aa = a
        self.bb = b

pp = Person(20, 40)
```

If I bring the Person `__init__` down to one parameter, then it works. If I raise it to 3, then I get the same `takes 1 but 3 were given` error. I'm totally stumped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared your Person class wrong. You used `def` instead of `class`, meaning that you actually have a function called Person with a local function called `__init__`.

Try this:

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.aa = a
        self.bb = b
```

Comment: Yes! The first time I've ever done this one... Found it here as you posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66549060/2183336

Comment: Have you not been sleeping very well perhaps? Lol. This happens to all of us at least once, or at least once a day in my case.