# How to successfully using GCS Filesystem to read a JPG File

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have two question:

1. How do I get the correct file
2. I know reading a jpg file may be different from a text, is there something in the code I need to be specially aware of?

This is on a line-bot application, I need to be able to read a jpg file that is uploaded as soon as the bot receieved the image from an end user.

I am using GCS filesystem to programmatically talk to GCS in Python once it uploads, but it's not scuuessful (I have revised my code a little bit), it give a new error message saying can't find the file:

```py
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\gcsfs\core.py", line 415, in _request
    validate_response(status, contents, path, args)
  File "C:\officiallandprice\myproject\myenv\lib\site-packages\gcsfs\retry.py", line 84, in validate_response
    raise FileNotFoundError(path)
FileNotFoundError: b/img_platecapture/o/%7Buser_id%7D.jpg
```

my blob name relates to the end user's line bot user_id. and the one it uploads is **completely different** than the one it reads(I am **using the same parameter)**

> [image: Blockquote]

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import vision
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
import fsspec
import gcsfs





def text_detected(user_id):
    fs=gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='My Project GoogleMap')
    with fs.open('img_platecapture/{user_id}.jpg','rb') as f:    #to get the file
        content=f.read()                                          #reading its content

    image = vision.Image(content=content)
    response = vision_client.text_detection(image=image)

    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))

    img = Image.open('img_platecapture/{user_id}.jpg')

     ...........

@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=ImageMessage)
def handle_content_message(event):
    message_content = line_bot_api.get_message_content(event.message.id)
    user = line_bot_api.get_profile(event.source.user_id) 

    data=b''
    for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
       data+= chunk

    global bucket_name   
    bucket_name = 'img_platecapture'
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(f'{user.user_id}.jpg')
    blob.upload_from_string(data)                      #upload the file
    text_detected1=text_detected(user.user_id)
    
    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        messages=TextSendMessage(
            text=text_detected1
    ))
```

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/typeerror-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-solved/) and this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328296/typeerror-person-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya thank you for the reply and the great reference link! I have reviced my code a little bit, if possible plz give me some more advice. Thank you!

Comment: can you go through this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74605414/how-to-read-a-jpg-from-google-storage-as-a-path-or-file-type) once

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Thank you for the reply, I think I’ve got some ideas

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I am now planning to deploy my code on google cloud function, so I think it might not be suitable to use downloas to file(), and I am trying on using gcsfs to get the file for PIL module to execute, (though, have little problem on python code), hope it might work  when I figure out the code. Appreciate for your asking.